# A strange print function bug

Tags: c++

I'm working on a InterviewStreet problem https://www.interviewstreet.com/challenges/dashboard/#problem/4fcf919f11817, the algorithm is correct but I still get several wrong answers, after several hours I find the problem is related with a print function:

```
void printHalf(int64_t x) {
    if (x % 2 == 0)
        printf("%lld\n", x / 2L);
    else
        printf("%lld.5\n", x / 2L);
}
```

This function takes a 64-bit integer, and print its half. If I change this function to the following code, my solution works on all test cases:

```
void printHalf(int64_t x) {
    if (x % 2 == 0)
        printf("%lld\n", x / 2L);
    else
        printf("%.1f\n", x / 2.0);
}
```

It looks a little weird to me, since in my opinion the two functions have the same results.

Comment: Can you give an example of one of the answers that's wrong with the first version?

Comment: @hall.stephenk I had no idea since that was what I was asking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first version doesn't handle the value `-1` properly. If you run `printHalf(-1)` it will print `0.5`, because it doesn't know that it needs to display `-0` instead of `0`.

For other negative values, it will work correctly in C++11, but relies on implementation-defined behavior in C++03 (the C++03 standard doesn't specify how division of negative numbers is rounded).

The second version may also print incorrect results: If the value is very large, the conversion to floating-point will reduce accuracy (since double-precision floating point can't represent all 64-bit integers accurately), so the result may be off by a little.

Comment: That's exactly where the problem is, thank you so much for pointing out!

Comment: As to the second version, the parameter x is actually within the range of a uint32_t, so I guess it can be represented in a double-precision floating point.